# Adding more than one class in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the below code

```
ArrayList<String> city = 'Anniston';

Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);

crit.add(Restrictions.eq("resumeSearchable", 1));
```

Now i want to add below criteria

```
crit.add(Restrictions.in("cities", city));
```

but the problem is that cities column is not in CandidateResumeInfo.class its in CandidateInfo Class.

Any idea how to add this criteria as well in the above one,how to add CandidateInfo class as well in the above criteria.

guess i need to do join or link these two tables but how ,and will there be any changes in the entity classes ?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the implementations of the two classes?

Comment: @Entity

@Table(name="candidateinfo")
public class CandidateInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

 private int id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String city;
 private String stateProvince;
 private String zip;
 private String country;
 
public CandidateInfo() {
 }
 @Column(name="userid")
 public int getId() {
  return this.id;
 }
 
 @Column(name="loginname")
 public String getLoginName() {
  return loginName;
 }
 public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
  this.loginName = loginName;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe your associations but I assume it would be something like

```
class CandidateResumeInfo {
  @OneToOne
  CandidateInfo candidate;
}
```

In this case you would need something like

```
ses.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq(...))
      .addCriteria('candidate')
      .add(Restrictions.in('cities',city);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

check section about associations.

Comment: thanks                                                         
I have this 
@Table(name="candidatResumeInfo")
Class CandidateResumeInfo{ ....

@OneToOne
CandidateInfo candidates;
....
}
then i have .. 

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);

crit.add(Restrictions.eq("resumeSearchable", 1));// resumeSearchable is in CandidateResume

crit.createCriteria("candidate")
.add(Restrictions.eq("userid",1)); // userid is in CandidateInfo Class

List rsList = crit.list(); //This is the next line  At this line it goes to exception and not giving any error

Comment: I'd be happy to help you, but please edit your question and add all code in formatted form. Otherwise it's very hard to decipher it. Secondly, `This is the next line At this line it goes to exception and not giving any error` - what is the exception? Stack trace? Also add it to question. Finally, did you notice that I used `candidate` and you say your class uses `candidates` property name? Please change your code to use `candidates` in criteria and see if it helps.

Comment: I have put each and every thing in below Answer( as it was not getting formatted here ) ,please try to resolve  thanks alot for your concern

Comment: I don't see anything. Edit your question and put it there. Did you try correct name `candidates`?

Comment: yes i checked the candidate thing ,i changed it ,no effect ,I post a new question for this   with title   Add two different tables is a single criteria (join )   kindly check that     Thanks   looking to hear from you